# Nodejs UDP socket send with array larger than MTU size

Tags: node.js, sockets, udp, mtu

I am currently using Nodejs to send UDP packets to Arduino with a Wiznet820io. I have successfully managed to send smallish byte arrays (500 bytes in length) however when I try to send to send a byte array greater than 1470 bytes I get nothing on the Arduino. I did some research and determined that it was silently failing due to the MTU size restriction.

So I attempted to split up the data array into multiple arrays not exceeding 1470 bytes and send them via a basic for loop. However, when doing this I noticed that only the first packet would get sent over unless I wait ~10ms before sending the next packet. I believe that this is due to the send function attempting to send the data before the previous data has been sent, However, i may be wrong in my understanding. Having the delay significantly reduces the speed of the server which is an issue as I am attempting to stream video.

Is there a proper way to parse and send packets over the UDP stream using dgram.send? Am I correct in my understanding of why only the first packet was retrieved? I am new to sockets so any help would be awesome :D

Cheers

Steve

Comment: Have you verified with a packet sniffer that the packet is not getting *sent* vs. just not getting *received*?  Doubtful that hardware is all that fast... it might not be able to keep up on the receive end.

Comment: You should send no more than 576 bytes per datagram. That way you can be guaranteed no fragmentation, and therefore less risk of datagram loss.